# Admob does not count displayed ads from phonegap app

Tags: javascript, admob, phonegap

Hello I have a small problem with phonegap. To display admob ads in my app I'm using a cordova-admob plugin.

I added this plugin using console "phonegap plugin add cordova-admob"

In my index.html in the app I added script to display:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    // Set AdMobAds options:
    admob.setOptions({
        publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
        interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
        tappxIdiOS:           "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",            // Optional
        tappxIdAndroid:       "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",        // Optional
        tappxShare:           0.5                                        // Optional
    });
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

But in this example the publisherId looks like Banner ID, so I addedmy banner ID there. The ads show, but admob does not count the views. Should I change the banner id to normal publisherid? But then where should I add the ID banner?